# Facebook Connect with multiple CNAMEs

Tags: facebook, cname

We have a single application that will be accessed by multiple CNAME routes.  Because Facebook Connect authorizes only 1 single URL for use, any CNAME route causes our Facebook Login to fail.  Multiple Domain capability on Facebook Apps does not solve the issue because each multiple domain: "must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL." (that is the exact error message given when multiple domains are attempted).

I can't imagine that someone as large as Facebook would have failed to account for CNAMEs ... but I cannot find any support for them in the documentation and any questions I see regarding this situation around the internet are left unanswered.

So the question is ... how to provide for Facebook Connect login with a single app accessed via many different CNAME routes?

Comment: This should work just fine (I do this on just about every app). Aren't your CNAMES derivatives of your base URL?

Comment: No, our CNAMEs are not derivatives of our base URL.  They are fully unique URL paths.

Comment: facebook apps only work with a base url and derivatives

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Facebook supports multiple domain names as of September 2011 (source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/).

Unfortunately, Facebook makes this a bit difficult still. The workaround we used was to add both base domain names (for example: domain1.com and domain2.com) into the domain name setting, then using the "Mobile URL" and "Site URL", we set a URL for each domain name, otherwise Facebook likes to throw an error saying "Error domain2.com must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL."

For example, in Site URL, you'd use a URL from domain1.com (i.e. myapp.domain1.com/index.php?) and for Mobile URL, you'd use a URL from domain2.com (i.e. myapp.domain2.com/index.php?).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution if you have only two base domain names.  We have a few more than that.  Thank you, however, for a creative solution that may be useful in other projects going forward.